# Accordion panel overlapping on select one to previously open(second) panel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added accordion on my site here https://www.freemakermedia.com/work-with-me/ here you can see "DONE-FOR-YOU WEBSITE" and "WEEKEND WEBSITE WARRIOR" two accordion fields added and by pressing on these its panel open, its all working fine. But my problem is the panel's are overlapping once open one panel to overlap exiting open panel.

I want to hide previously open panel so they will not overlap each other. I have tried different solutions to hide previously open panel when click on second accordion field but no luck. Below is my JS code.

```
        //Js file for accordian

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordian-left");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            panel.style.zIndex = "0";
            panel.style.border = "0";
            } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        jQuery(this).css('margin-bottom','10px');
        panel.style.zIndex = "1";
        panel.style.border = "3px solid #eee";
        } 
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function before `this.classList.toggle("active");` you could reset every accordion with a for loop to be not active.
Or combine everything in a for loop to hide every other panel and run the toggle only on the clicked one:

```
function showPanel(panel) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    jQuery(this).css('margin-bottom','10px');
    panel.style.zIndex = "1";
    panel.style.border = "3px solid #eee";
}

function hidePanel(panel) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    panel.style.zIndex = "0";
    panel.style.border = "0";
}

function togglePanel(panel) {
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        hidePanel(panel);
    } else {
        showPanel(panel);
    }
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordian-left");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        var hideAnim = false;
        for (j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
            if (this != acc[j] && acc[j].classList.contains("active")) {
                acc[j].classList.remove("active");
                hidePanel(acc[j].nextElementSibling);
                hideAnim = true;
            }
        }
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (hideAnim) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              togglePanel(panel);
            }, 400);
        } else {
            togglePanel(panel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes its working, but now the toggle hide/show not working

Comment: @Barjinder I left out an if and continue in the for loop. Edited my answer, please check with this one again.

Comment: Thank you @David. Its worked perfectly well. Can we add little bit animate effect while open and hide panel or just can little bit slow down while open?

Comment: Sure, I edited it again. Added a new togglePanel function which can be called for toggling. Also added a setTimeout, which executes the first function parameter after second parameter (in miliseconds). Currently it is 400. You can fine tune it to your liking.